# How can i remove category title (H1) from a specific page of catalog?

Tags: catalog, page-title

How can i remove category title (H1) from a specific page of catalog? 
I deleted breadcrumbs using a code xml:

```
 <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
```

Is it possible to replicate this with H1? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that via xml layouts only.
But you have a few other options. All of them require some coding.

**Option 1** - Quick and dirty
Edit `app/design/frontned/{package}/{theme}/catalog/product/category/view.phtml` and add an `if statement` around the `h1` tag. Something like this:

```
if ($_category->getId() != 44) { //your category id here
    //h1 tag here
}
```

**Option 2** - with attributes.
Add a new yes/no attribute to the category called `hide_title`.
Then you need to edit the same template as in option 1 and add this `if` statement

```
if (!$_category->getHideTitle()) {
    //h1 tag here
}
```

I would use this approach. This way you can always hide the title from the backend for every category you need.

**Option 3** - no attributes but a new theme.
Create a new theme inside your package.
Let's call it `no_title`.
This theme should contain only one file. The category view template:
`app/design/frontned/{package}/no_title/catalog/product/category/view.phtml`.
This has to be a clone of your normal view file from your theme with just the `h1` tag removed.
Then, for the categories you don't want the title you set them to use this new theme from the design settings tab in the backend.

Comment: Thank you! In my opinion the third option is the most correct!

Comment: I don't know why, but option 3 bugs me. Creating a new theme to be used only for a single category page's template seems awkward. Option 2 seems like it would be more obvious to the next guy.

Comment: I didn't say option 3 is the best. i sayd it can be a solution. i would actually do this. for example, if i latrer change the theme of my website i can still use the one i created for the special categories without having to modify my new theme (lets say i bought my new theme online).

Comment: This can now be done with XML layouts, see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

**Option 4 -** You can add this under the "custom design" tab in a category. Just copy the original view.phtml. Edit the title section to either remove it or comment out.

The path to this file is: /your_theme/template/catalog/category/

```
<reference name="category.products">   
 <action method="setTemplate">       
  <template>catalog/category/your-view.phtml</template>   
 </action>
</reference>
```

Cheers ~ Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in a pure XML method. However it can be done via the admin for a specific category.
Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories -> select the category to edit -> click Custom Design tab -> inside Custom Layout Update add this code:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="core/text" name="hide.heading">
      <action method="setText">
        <text>
           <![CDATA[
                <style type="text/css">
                    .category-title { display: none; }
                </style>
            ]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: This can now be done with XML layouts, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This **CAN NOW** be done with XML in versions >= 2.3.4

in: `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME_NAME/Magento_Catalog/layout/`

create: `catalog_category_view_selectable_[CATID]_[CATNAME].xml`

where [CATID] is the ID of the Category and [CATNAME] is the lowercase name of the category with all spaces removed. eg: *Womens Dress Skirts* becomes *womensdressskirts*

add code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Now in **admin > catalog > Categories > (eg)Womens Dress Skirts**, under **Design** you'll see a dropdown labelled **Custom Layout Update**. Change that to (eg) *womensdressskirts*. Save, clear your cache and the H1 will be gone.

Works with any block on any specific category.

Learned from Rakesh Jesadiya here: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-category-custom-layout-update-xml-file-magento-2-3-4/